# How to get result with ORM from queryset. (python, django)

Tags: python, django, orm

I want to get result with ORM of Django. But I cannot get result with ORM.
I just tried with 'select_related("field_name")'. but doesn't work..
Actually, I don't know using ORM well haha...

and.. 
This **Query** is my needs

```
SELECT sol.idx, sol.sol_name, sol.sol_warning, sol.user_num_id, sol.auto_run_server, ur.user_ip,
pc.cpu_usage, pc.mem_usage, pc.disk_usage FROM solution AS sol 
INNER JOIN ems.user AS ur ON sol.user_num_id = ur.user_num INNER JOIN pc_status AS pc ON sol.user_num_id = pc.user_num_id;
```

result row is ...

```
idx, sol_name, sol_warning, user_num_id, auto_run_server, user_ip, cpu_usage, mem_usage, disk_usage
```

so.. 
I used code is " Solution.objects.select_related('user_num') "
But I cannot get same result.

here are my python codes.

```
models.py

class User(models.Model):
    user_num = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    user_ip = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    user_pwd = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'


class Solution(models.Model):
    idx = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    sol_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sol_warning = models.IntegerField()
    user_num = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    auto_run_server = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'solution' 


class PcStatus(models.Model):
    pc_idx = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    cpu_usage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    mem_usage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    disk_usage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user_num = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'pc_status'
```

Comment: use `MyModel.objects.filter(some_field=some_value)` to query your model.

Comment: you can retrieve all the objects using the filter on your model object such as below: 
example: your model is PcStatus so it will be like, PcStatus.objects.all() will return you all the objects. Apart from that, you can use queries like contains, equal to ans so on. Please find reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/

Comment: tooooo late .. thank you guys